# Where can I get freely available audio, graphics, and other resources for games?

Tags: audio, graphics

I've done a google search of this topic, but so far haven't found anything satisfactory.

From your experience, what's the best place to get game resources, like sprites, backgrounds, sound effects, music, etc.?  To be more specific, I'm looking for more of sound effects and music, which I'm currently lacking more than graphics.  However, for graphics, I've tried getting random graphics from different sites, but they just don't match. I don't want to copy one entire graphics package either.

The resources should be free and easy to obtain. The products I intend to make are free if not open source, and are unlikely to receive widespread attention or produce profit for myself, so I'd like something that I can use and distribute freely.

I don't have enough graphics and musical knowledge to attempt to create resources from scratch and don't know anyone willing to do so.

I'm working with Java. I'm sure I can read all kinds of file formats with it, or if not, I can always use software to convert resources.

Comment: Is this for a specific project or just a general question, did you have a theme in mind? Do you want to be able to sell the end product or is just for personal use?

Comment: It's actually somewhere in between. Although I don't intend to profit from my product I'm looking to create a reasonably appealing one.

Comment: not a programming question. Try http://www.gamedev.net/

Comment: true although i'm still interested in getting an answer.

Comment: Totally a programming question and stackoverflow is the easiest question and answer website. Best answers rise to the top. No digging

Comment: For free sounds, music, textures and art: OpenGameArt.org

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In terms of graphics, Daniel Cook of [Lost Garden](http://www.lostgarden.com) produces some seriously high quality, reusable game art that is free for both personal and commercial work (read his [license](http://lostgarden.com/2007/03/lost-garden-license.html) details). Here's the index of his [free graphics](http://lostgarden.com/labels/free%20game%20graphics.html) related posts, just hit the "read more" link at the bottom of an article and you'll find links to the downloads.

***edit:*** in terms of sound effects, [Soundrangers](http://www.soundrangers.com) is pretty decent if you have something specific in mind, but it can quickly get expensive. For a complex game, if you're wanting a rich user experience you'll need dozens, if not hundreds of sound effects. At a couple of bucks a pop, that adds up real quick. A lot of places (including [Soundrangers](http://www.soundrangers.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=category.display&Category_id=591)) offer thematic sound packs which give you a little more bang for your buck, but it's still not free. GameDev also has a [listing of audio resources](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/list.asp?categoryid=4).

For music, I think your options are better. Depending on what kind of thing you're looking for (ambient, instrumental, vocal etc). I would seriously think about approaching local independent musicians and using existing tracks that they have. They're likely to let you use their music for free (properly accredited of course) or at a reasonable cost.

Comment: I can't hear any of the previews at soundrangers.  Did anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 5):

There's http://www.freesound.org/

Most stuff there has a license that is incompatible with, say, Fedora, for instance, though if you ask the copyright holder sometimes they'll license things under a different license.

Music is harder to come by than sound effects.  you could try digging around on archive.org, say here: http://www.archive.org/details/muzic

Also check out sfxr http://www.cyd.liu.se/~tompe573/hp/project_sfxr.html
though the sounds that it makes are pretty old school sounding -- and if that's what you're looking for, it's cool, otherwise, it can make some place holder sound effects.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for interesting textures, I would suggest checking out [Filter Forge](http://www.filterforge.com/filters/). You can download the filters for use in Adobe Photoshop, or you can potentially use the sample images on the site to create texture maps for various types of terrains and materials.

Answer (score 1):

GarageGames.com sells a lot of that kind of thing... 3d models, textures, background music and so on.

http://garagegames.com and specifically http://www.garagegames.com/products/browse

HTH

edit: whoops, I didn't see the "free" requirement! Do a search on "creative commons" and you'll find lots of music, at least, and some graphics.

Comment: Hmm their products are fairly expensive and more than I'm willing to pay for my personal use.

Comment: Some of them are expensive, but many are $30 or less. It's far from out of reach, but for sure more than free. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is the type of thing you're looking for, but [Game Sprite Archives](http://www.gsarchives.net/index2.php) has a huge huge collection of SNES/NES/Anything pre-playstation 1 sprite rips.

Comment: I would be surprised if much of the content on that site is legal to use.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered this site the other day while looking for some sound effects:

http://www.soundrangers.com/

It looks like they're royalty-free but most of the sounds cost a buck or two.  Looks like some sounds are free though.

Answer (score 0):

**Clipart**

- [Open Clip Art](http://www.openclipart.org/)

**Textures**

- [ImageAfter](http://www.imageafter.com/textures.php)
- [CG Textures](http://www.cgtextures.com/)
- [OpenFootage](http://www.openfootage.net/)
- [Texture Hound](http://www.texturehound.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Sound Snap](http://www.soundsnap.com), they allow 5 free downloads for a month for the free accounts, and more if you sign up. I have been using them for the past couple of months for the games I have developed.